# How to read json file into dataframe?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as plt
from ast import literal_eval
import json

%matplotlib inline
with open('today.json') as f:
data = literal_eval(f.read())
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-16-6c3ee58610d7>", line 10

    data = literal_eval(f.read())

   ^

IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Jupyter doesn't matter, but `json.load` is what you need, not literal eval

Comment: And your error seems to be about indentation (which is important in Python), not error isn't about the json, so I'm voting to close as a typo

Answer (score -1):

`pd.read_json()` is what you need:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

You would simply use `df = pd.read_json('today.json')`